# Alfresco : searching filed which for specific Metadata field

Tags: lucene, alfresco

In Alfresco we have the **JSON** representation of **Metadata** fields of a file. The following one is for an Image file:

```
{
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "downloadUrl": "",
    "content": {
        "type": null,
        "version": "",
        "attributes": {
            "resolutionUnit": "Inch",
            "software": "Adobe Photoshop"   
        },
        "newContentIconDuration": null,
        "creationDate": "2016-08-03T14:58:32.656-04:00"
    }
}
```

I am working on requirement to search all images files, which contains Metadata field **"software": "Adobe Photoshop"** (as we can see in above json structure).

By using the following code I can search all files in alfresco, which have *'mimeType' 'image/jpeg'*, but not sure **how can I search for metadata "software": "Adobe Photoshop"** ?

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:content.mimetype:\"image/png\"");
```

Any suggestion please  ?

Comment: Is that JSON you have stored as a node? If so, what happens if you follow the "alfresco way" and store your metadata as properties?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it now by using this statement :

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@exif\\:software:\"Adobe Photoshop\"");
```

Steps to get this field name is ==> go to Alfresco Admin Consile -> Node Browser
and put this value in **PATH** field with '**Nodref**" selected : "*workspace://SpacesStore/REFERENCEIDOFTHEFILE*" . There we can see the Name of fields which is being used. Like in this case it is **exif:software**.